# Bit AND amongst all natural numbers lying between A and B (both inclusive)

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I came across this problem on a competitive problem site. 
Here is the problem:-

**Problem Statement**

You will be given two integers A and B. You are required to compute the bitwise AND amongst all natural numbers lying between A and B (both inclusive).

Fix the code in the editor so that it solves the problem above. You need to complete the missing line marked by "~~Fill this line". Don't modify or insert any other lines, otherwise you will get a wrong answer even if your code is correct.

**Input Format**

First line of the input contains T, the number of testcases to follow. Each testcase in a newline contains A and B separated by a single space.

**Constraints**:

```
1<=T<=200
0≤A≤B<2^32
```

**Output Format**
Output one line per test case with the required bitwise AND.

**Sample Input**

3

12 15

2 3

8 13

**Sample Output**

12

2

8

Here is the code wherein we have to fill the missing line :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Magic4 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      int T = scanner.nextInt();

      for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
         long l = scanner.nextLong();
         long r = scanner.nextLong();
         long res = 0;
         for (long i = 0; i < 32; i++) {// I can make out that we are dealing with 32 bit numbers hence we are setting the condition as i < 32, but after that the proceedings in the loop are vague.
            if ((r - l + 1 == 1))
               if(l%2==1)
                  ~~Fill this line~~
            l >>= 1; r >>= 1;
         }
         System.out.println(res);
      }

      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

**Problem** I just could not solve it, i.e filling with the correct line even after spending some time. I can make out that we are dealing with 32 bit numbers hence we are setting the condition as i < 32, but after that the proceedings in the loop are vague. If you can make out something do let me know.

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: I tried res += (l & r);

Comment: Is that all you tried?  I think you need to try a bit harder ...

Comment: Well I need some hint, if I get to know why are we doing if ((r - l + 1 == 1)) and if(l%2 == 1), I would be in a better position to try. I understand if(l%2==1) means we are filtering out even values of l.

Comment: For a single case, using a computer seems excessive - start by assuming `A` equals 0, 1 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = res | (1 << i);
```

Each iteration of the loop tests if the `32-i` left-most bits of the two numbers (A and B, or `l` and `r` in the code) are equal to each other. If they are, the result of bit-wise AND of all the numbers between A and B must contain 1 for each of the `32-i` bits of A (or B) that contain 1.

So if `r - l + 1 == 1` (i.e. r==l) and `l%2==1`, the `i`'th bit of the result must be 1.

Comment: Interesting, I solved this problem with a bit different approach: `{res = l<<i; break;} else {res = l<<i; break;} else if (l==0) {res = 0; break;}`;  Condition `if(l%2==1)` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Aivean I followed the rules of just adding a line of code at the specified location without changing anything.

Comment: I too. I just had to add the same code in both branches to "bypass" if.

Comment: Please clarify Why do we need l%2==1 in the condition?

Comment: @JohnDoe There's are several ways to implement this task, and some of them don't require this condition. `l%2==1` means that the right-most bit of the top `32-i` bits of `l` is 1. Which means the implementation dictated by the code in this challenge leads you to a solution in which in each iteration you set the `i`'th bit to 1 if necessary.

Comment: Isn't this code itself wrong to calculate 'and' of all numbers from l to r. It's valid only for all l ans r which are between two consecutive powers of 2 I.e. all l and r between 2 to 4, 4 to 8, 8 to 16 etc...Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @instance You are wrong. Take for example the range 5 to 7, or 101 to 111 (I'm ignoring all but the lowest 3 bits, since all the other bits are 0). Since both 101 and 111 have 1 in the 3rd bit, all the numbers between 5 and 7 have 1 in that bit, and the result of ANDing all of them would be 100.

Comment: @Eran I agree but my point was if I take 5 and 10, it returns 0. Let me simplify my previous comment, if l and r has different number of bits, this code is not working.

Comment: @instance For 5 and 10 the code should return 0. The numbers from 5 to 10 are 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000, 1001 and 1100. AND all those numbers and you get 0.

Comment: Oops...my bad...yes you are right. I was just writing all number and doing and together just by counting 1s...so silly of me.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized code (Tested on Hackerrank)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int nTestCases;
    unsigned int nStart, nEnd;

    scanf("%d", &nTestCases);

    while (nTestCases--)
    {
        scanf("%u %u", &nStart, &nEnd);
        unsigned int nWalk = (nEnd - nStart);
        unsigned int nMask = 1;
        while (nWalk)
        {
            nWalk >>= 1;
            nMask <<= 1;
        }
        nMask = nMask - 1;

        printf("%u\n", (nStart & ~nMask & nEnd));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: KIndly add some explanation also for the greater benefit of all.